# How to count the number of T/F observations in chain functions using dplyr or base R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a tbl_df called `pokemons` like this:

```
      X.                  Name Type.1 Type.2 Total    HP Attack Defense Sp..Atk Sp..Def Speed Generation Legendary
    (int)                (fctr) (fctr) (fctr) (int) (int)  (int)   (int)   (int)   (int) (int)      (int)    (fctr)
 1     1             Bulbasaur  Grass Poison   318    45     49      49      65      65    45          1     False
 2     2               Ivysaur  Grass Poison   405    60     62      63      80      80    60          1     False
 3     3              Venusaur  Grass Poison   525    80     82      83     100     100    80          1     False
 4     3 VenusaurMega Venusaur  Grass Poison   625    80    100     123     122     120    80          1     False
 5     4            Charmander   Fire          309    39     52      43      60      50    65          1     False
 6     5            Charmeleon   Fire          405    58     64      58      80      65    80          1     False
```

I am writing a chain function (using the package `dplyr`) to summarize the important stats of the dataset, as followed:

```
byType1 <- group_by(pokemons, Type.1)
summaryStats_byType1 <- summarise(byType1,
               count = n(),
               averageTotal = mean(Total, na.rm = T),
               medianGeneration = median(Generation, na.rm = T))
```

How should I go about counting the number of legendary pokemons in the chain function above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do

```
summaryStats_byType1  <-  pokemons %>%
                            group_by(Type.1) %>%
                            summarise(count = n(),
                                averageTotal = mean(Total, na.rm = T),
                                medianGeneration = median(Generation, na.rm = T),
                                CountLegendary = sum(as.character(Legendary)=="True"))
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't pay enough attention to realize the "True"/"False" were strings, not logical T/F.

Comment: @KatieTruong  In `R`, the correct option is `TRUE` `FALSE~ without any quotes.  Also it is better not to abbreviate with T or F as this can lead to problems when a object name is defined with those.